# How do I remove operations tracking in Cyberduck

Tags: cyberduck

I don't know how but somehow this window displays the operations for each file. It's the bottom window. I've tried to find out what caused it. I've looked through all the preferences and settings. I tried googling to the best of my ability. I have asked numerous people, but I cannot find an answer. Please, you are my last hope for my sanity.

[image: cyberduck]

Comment: This question is off-topic and should be moved to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the menu bar, select "View > Toggle Log Drawer" or Command-L to show or hide the log drawer.

[image]